# How to upload image in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am working on a e-commerce app and there I am using form to add new product in app for that I am taking multiple inputs from user and then I am storing those inputs in my redux store and finally I am displaying newly added product in my app and everything is working perfectly here earlier I was using `<input type="url"/>` so user can paste an image url so I can display it and it was working perfectly but now I want to allow user so he can upload an Image from his local system instead or url using `<input type="file"/>` but this isn,t working this is not loading image from local system so is there any way I can upload Image from local system:

**Form**

```
import "./ProductForm.css";
import { useReducer } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addProductHandler } from "../../store/DataStore";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const ProductForm = () => {
  const Dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const initialState = {
    product_id: "",
    product_name: "",
    product_quantity: "",
    product_description: "",
    product_type: "",
    product_valid: "false",
    product_price: "",
    product_title: "",
    product_image: "",
  };
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "id") {
      return { ...state, product_id: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "name") {
      return { ...state, product_name: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "title") {
      return { ...state, product_title: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "price") {
      return { ...state, product_price: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "image") {
      return { ...state, product_image: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "description") {
      return { ...state, product_discription: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "type") {
      return { ...state, product_type: action.value };
    }
  };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const obj = {
      product_id: state.product_id,
      product_name: state.product_name,
      product_price: +state.product_price,
      product_title: state.product_title,
      product_image: state.product_image,
      product_type: state.product_type,
      product_description: state.product_discription,
      product_quantity: 0,
      product_valid: "false",
    };
    console.log(obj);
    // Dispatch(addProductHandler(obj));
    // navigate(`/product`, { replace: true });
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <legend>
        <center>
          <h2>
            <b>Add Product</b>
          </h2>
        </center>
      </legend>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product id</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_id}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "id", value: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_name}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "name", value: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product Price</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_price}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "price", value: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product Title</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_title}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "title", value: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product Type</label>
        <select
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_type}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "type", value: e.target.value })}
        >
          <option value="" selected disabled>
            Select one
          </option>
          <option value="c1">Commodityies</option>
          <option value="g1">Gadgets</option>
          <option value="w1">Wearings</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product Image</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_image}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "image", value: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product Description</label>
        <textarea
          className="form-control"
          id=""
          rows="7"
          value={state.product_discription}
          onChange={(e) =>
            dispatch({ type: "description", value: e.target.value })
          }
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-4">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ProductForm;
```

Answer (score -1):

you cannot upload file like that you should have to use FormData Class  For multipart/form-data

```
var formData = new FormData();
 
  formData.append('product_id', state.product_id,)
  formData.append('product_name', state.product_name,)
  formData.append('product_price', +state.product_price,)
  formData.append('product_title', state.product_title,)
  formData.append('product_image', state.product_image,)
  formData.append('product_type', state.product_type,)
  formData.append('product_description', state.product_discription,)
  formData.append('product_quantity', 0,)
  formData.append('product_valid', "false") 

  formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 



$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
    // ... Other options like success and etc
});
```

After this it will send ajax request like you submit regular form
with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: What I have to pass in url?